# Thread.sleep has the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

i am doing some works for my test and i got this feeling that sleep doesnt work,you have to choose from combobox 100ms 300ms 500ms 1000ms.But when i start program and they do it it looks same maybe i made some error.
Thanks in advance.
HERE IS MY CODE :

```
package vjezbanje;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Move extends Thread {

    JComboBox cb = new JComboBox();
    JLabel lb = new JLabel();
    JPanel pl = new JPanel();
    ImageIcon ic;
    private String[] brzine = {"100ms","300ms","500ms","1000ms"};   

    public JComboBox getCb() {
        return cb;
    }

    public void setCb(JComboBox cb) {
        this.cb = cb;
    }

    public JLabel getLb() {
        return lb;
    }

    public void setLb(JLabel lb) {
        this.lb = lb;
    }

    public JPanel getPl() {
        return pl;
    }

    public void setPl(JPanel pl) {
        this.pl = pl;
    }

    public Move() {                     
    }

    public void run() {

        pl.add(lb);
        cb = new JComboBox(brzine);

        for(int t=0; t<10; t++) {
        if(cb.getSelectedItem().equals("100ms")) {
            try {

                Random r = new Random ();
                int s = r.nextInt(6)+1;
                // 0 1 2 3 4 5
                lb.setIcon(new ImageIcon("slike\\"+s+".jpg"));
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }                   

        if(cb.getSelectedItem().equals("300ms")) {
            try {

                Random r = new Random ();
                int s = r.nextInt(6)+1;
                // 0 1 2 3 4 5
                lb.setIcon(new ImageIcon("slike\\"+s+".jpg"));
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }       

        if(cb.getSelectedItem().equals("500ms")) {
            try {

                Random r = new Random ();
                int s = r.nextInt(6)+1;
                // 0 1 2 3 4 5
                lb.setIcon(new ImageIcon("slike\\"+s+".jpg"));
                Thread.sleep(500);          
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }


        if(cb.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("1000ms")) {
            try {

                Random r = new Random ();
                int s = r.nextInt(6)+1;
                // 0 1 2 3 4 5
                lb.setIcon(new ImageIcon("slike\\"+s+".jpg"));
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }               
    }               
}
```

Comment: Wow.  How about defining an array of long so you don't have to have your if blocks.  Then the code size divides by 4.  Wow.

Comment: Can you edit your question some more to improve the english (uppercase and punctuation is recommended), and to explain what output you are getting that you don't understand?

Comment: Also how can you tell if they are different? there is no timing,or printing after you wait

Comment: You are making a separate thread sleep as the last thing it does before ending. You also call Swing methods from outside the Event Dispatch Thread, so I wonder how this works at all.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/fu5hev/5 this is what i get.in program there is Combo box in which i defined length of sleep.And when i start it those dices look like they are turning but whatever speed i choose 100 300 500 1000 ms it looks same. i hope this 1 was better .Sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Gray, that should be one block with a variable for sleep time.
However, I think what you're asking is "why don't I see my images changing at different times?". What you're likely seeing is just a "hang" for different lengths of time. That's because you're doing all the updates on the GUI thread, including the sleep, so nothing actually updates until your entire method returns.

There would be various ways to update in the background. I might recommend some kind of background worker that allows progress updates. Use the progress update to change the image, and the worker method to sleep.

Comment: Thanks i think i found way out now :)